# Paths in Java with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, path, processbuilder, 7zip

I have this line of code:

```
new ProcessBuilder(C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zFM.exe);
```

But, if I run my app in a different pc, with a different path, I would like to know, How could I know this path if they have 7zip installed? Thnks.

Comment: You wouldn't. Don't depend on something being installed on a user's computer. If your application requires it, make it part of your application and/or installation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn´t know, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't find out where it is installed.you can take the installed path as programe parameter or ask the user at run time to enter the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should never depend on anything being installed on a user's computer. If you have to then you need to have your program ask them for the path to the file. But, there's really no need to in your case because 7zip publishes [a Java API](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).